# How to create unfocussed,enabled edittextbox in android

Tags: android

i've created one searchEditBox and a button.Initially when the page loads.,the searchEditBox will be focussed with orange color mark automatically.when i use searchValue.setFocusable(false);.,its unfocussed but i couldnt able to type anything on that box(Box will be disabled).How could i recover this probs.?

java:

setContentView(R.layout.main);
        edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
        but=(Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
        edit.setFocusable(false);

xml:

Comment: Could you please post your codes, Without looking at your code we cannot help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will solve your problem. Add the android:focusableInTouchMode="true" to your linearLayout that holds your EditText in your mail.xml file.

ie:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```

This worked for me. Very simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

comment your `edit.setFocusable(false);`

use `searchValue.requestFocus()` to set focus on EditText. It will work for you.

Check the following code.

### Activity

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.admob);

         // Lookup R.layout.main
       EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);

       Button but=(Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
//       edit.setFocusable(false);
       edit.requestFocus();
    }
```

### admob.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="250px" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       />
        <Button android:id="@+id/but"
         android:layout_width="80px"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="click"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Donot forget to vote if my response is helpful for you.

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: @Deepak..nope its not working.But i need to remove those orange outline(i.e initially not focus on it).

Comment: Can you post your source code? Because I tried at my end It worked fine. Let me go though your code.

Comment: deepak..i've posted my code.now its unfocussed.But i cant able to type anything on edittextbox

Comment: Check my answer now. It is working. comment your edit.setFocusable(false)

Comment: i used edit.requestFocus() too..But still i have that unwanted orange outline(i.e focus)

Comment: I checked in my program. My focus come to EditText by default. I am using android 2.3.3 emulator. Did you create sample program with the code that I have given you?